# Monotouch - Not sure how to handle NavController & Toolbar

Tags: xamarin.ios

I want each of my views to have their own toolbar buttons, particular to what you're trying to do.

In my MainWindow.XIB I've added a NavigationController.

I thought the best way to do this would be to add a toolbar to each view I want to create. However this means that the initial NavigationController is 'empty' and so immediately when I Push my 'first real view' on, I end up with a back button.

When I tried the approach of having the NavigationController have a toolbar, and to override them in each view, it worked fine for the views but not for the navigationcontroller.

I'm not sure which approach, or if another, is the best way to go. Advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, I realized I was thinking about the NavigationController and its responsibilities incorrectly when it came to what I wanted to do.

I decided to strip the NavigationController to where it only provides the header, and then put the responsibility for having Toolbars on each of the views IF I needed them. Also with this I programmatically controlled the Back button from appearing when I pushed my "first" (because really the NavigationController's view is the 'first' view) view on the stack. Now the behavior is as desired.